# How test input onChange event with enzyme?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I made TextInput component, here is code:

```
export const TextInput = (props: ITextInputProps): TReactElement => {
  const {
    errorMessage,
    hasError,
    ...restProps
  } = props;

  return (
    <div>
      <input
        { ...restProps }
        type="text"
        className={ mergeClassNames([
          textInputStyles["text-input"],
          hasError ? textInputStyles["text-input--error"] : "",
        ]) }
      />
      {
        hasError &&
        <p className={ textInputStyles["text-input__error-message"] }>{ errorMessage }</p>
      }
    </div>
    );
};
```

Now I wont test that onChange work correctly, I do it like this:

```
test("TextInput: should change value", () => {
  let actualInputValue;

  const textInputProps = {
    onChange: (event: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>): void => {
      actualInputValue = event.currentTarget.value;
    },
  };

  const textInputWrapper = shallow(<TextInput { ...textInputProps } />);

  textInputWrapper.find(".text-input")
    .simulate("change", {
      currentTarget: {
        value: "Hello, world!",
      },
    });

  expect(actualInputValue)
    .toBe("Hello, world!");
});
```

I feel that actualInputValue and onChange handler is excess because I can get value directly from .text-input

I tried read value like this (but got undefined):

```
test("TextInput: should change value", () => {
  const textInputWrapper = shallow(<TextInput />);

  textInputWrapper.find(".text-input")
    .simulate("change", {
      currentTarget: {
        value: "Hello, world!",
      },
    });

  expect(textInputWrapper.find(".text-input").props().value)
    .toBe("Hello, world!");
});
```

Then I tried update textInputWrapper like this (but got undefined):

```
test("TextInput: should change value", () => {
  const textInputWrapper = shallow(<TextInput />);

  textInputWrapper.find(".text-input")
    .simulate("change", {
      currentTarget: {
        value: "Hello, world!",
      },
    });

  textInputWrapper.update();

  expect(textInputWrapper.find(".text-input").props().value)
    .toBe("Hello, world!");
});
```

Then I also tried use done callback (but got undefined):

```
test("TextInput: should change value", (done: () => void) => {
  const textInputWrapper = shallow(<TextInput />);

  textInputWrapper.find(".text-input")
    .simulate("change", {
      currentTarget: {
        value: "Hello, world!",
      },
    });

  textInputWrapper.update();

  expect(textInputWrapper.find(".text-input").props().value)
    .toBe("Hello, world!");

  done();
});
```

I also used mount instead shallow and got same results...

Then I used actualInputValue and onChange handler :(

It's my questions: how to get actual value from textInputWrapper.find(".text-input") ?

Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 0):

I think the main issue you're having is within your expect statement (below)

```
expect(textInputWrapper.find(".text-input").props().value)
.toBe("Hello, world!");
```

You're running `.props()` on an array instead of a single node, assuming you know there will be only one `".text-input"` replace it with the below.

```
expect(textInputWrapper.find(".text-input").at(0).props().value)
.toBe("Hello, world!");
```

You could also use `.prop("value")` instead of `.props().value` although that's more personal preference.

Also you don't need to use the done callback for this test, that's only for async functions such as MockApi calls

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I still have undefined.

**console.log(textInputWrapper.find(".text-input").at(0).props())**

This code emit only react props { type: 'text', className: 'text-input ' }. I don't see default html props like as value :(

Do you have any reason?

Comment: Also **textInputWrapper.find(".text-input").html()** return  <input type="text" class="text-input "/>. I don't see input's value :(

Comment: if `find()` returns more than 1 node then test will fail. So there is no need to do explicitly `.at(0)`. Even more: doing that you need explicitly verify if there is just single node found by `.toHaveLength(1)`. So better leave that as it is.